# How to get the 'id' of the data in datatables to display the data in the update form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I am using laravel and datatables. I want to update the data, but I don't know how to get the id of the data in my datatables if the update form is a new page/link.
If the update form is a modal/popup, I am using:

```
<a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update_modal" onclick="update_modal('{{ $getData->data_id }}')"></a>
```

In the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function update_modal(data_id) {
     $('#update_id_text').val(data_id);
   }
</script>
```

And it will display the data on my database to a textbox in a modal. But how if I want to make that modal is not a modal, but a new page?
what should I do with this:

```
<a href="{{ route('UpdateData')}}" type="button"></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the variable `data_id` as parameter to the new page through the route :

```
<a href="{{ route('UpdateData',['data_id'=>$getData->data_id])}}" type="button"></a>
```

Then in the input `#update_id_text` assign this value using :

```
<input type="text" value="{{$data_id}}" id="update_id_text"/>
```

Or you could get it in controller the using `INPUT::get()`, like :

```
$data_id = INPUT::get("data_id");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: damn you're faster for answering this question +1

Comment: actually i need the 'data_id' in my query in controller to show the data detail in my view? like 'select name, age from custTable where data_id = $data_id. do you know how to put the data_id into the $data_id in my controller?

Comment: when I print_r the $data_id, it shows nothing just a white blank page, but it shows data_id=2 in the link

Comment: Try to print it using  `dd(INPUT::get("data_id"))`

Comment: Ok please add your controller action to the OP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127636/discussion-between-hendraspt-and-zakaria-acharki).